# AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'train'

Tags: python, tensorflow, collections, tensorboard, ordereddictionary

```
with summary_writer.as_default():
  for round_num in range(1, NUM_ROUNDS):
    state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)
    # for name, value in metrics.train._asdict().items():
    tf.summary.scalar('metrics', metrics.train._asdict().itrems(), step=round_num)
```

I am just stuck here. I am getting error messages as:
*AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'train'*
Metrics looks like this:

```
metrics=OrderedDict([('broadcast', ()), ('aggregation', ()), ('train', OrderedDict([('sparse_categorical_accuracy', 0.12695473), ('loss', 3.0522373)]))])
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `metrics.train`, try `metrics['train']`.

Comment: ..and `itrems` should be `items`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like

```
metrics.train._asdict().itrems()
```

should be

```
metrics['train'].items()
```